# Source of cell content in a cell range but not mandatory

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to set the source of some cells to a specific column of another sheet's column. This is easy:

You select a cell, you go to Data validation, Choose List for the Allow setting, and then choose the desired range for the Source setting. Then you fill-down up to the rest cells you want to control their content entry.

But then, you're forced to use a value from that list you defined before. What I want is to be able to pick a value from that list, but also have the ability to type a totally different value if you need to.

Please don't suggest that I go to that list range and type the new content there. This is something I can't tell to the user of that workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t want an alert message to show up, clear the check box "Show error alert after invalid data is entered".
[Data Validation error alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu3Na.png)

Comment: It's not the alert the problem. I need to be able to freely type some new cell content. Maybe I should drop the whole validation altogether.

Comment: I mean, I need to be able to choose the cell contents from a specific drop-down list, and that's exactly what data validation offered me so that's why I used them. It's not the validation that I needed. It's the drop-down list I needed. If I can use some other feature of Excel to set the data-source of a cell to some other cells, and the options be presented in a drop-down similar to data validation's, then I'd gladly use that instead.

Comment: Did you try? If you disable alerts you can still choose anything from the drop-down list or enter anything else to the cell (without alert). What more do you need?

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and it works exactly as I needed it to! I had never paid attention to those additional settings tabs!